# Is there a way to customize keys returned by result_array() in CodeIgniter 3?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

Hope you can help me with the following problem. Detail:

**Context.** I work with CodeIgniter 3 and I'm executing this query against a database:

```
$query = $this->db->get('animals')->result_array();
```

**What I get.** The query returns an array like this:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [id] => 27
        [created_at] =>
        [updated_at] =>
        [name] => Abc
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [id] => 35
        [created_at] =>
        [updated_at] =>
        [name] => Def
    )
)
```

**What I want to get:**

```
Array (
    [27] => Array (
        [id] => 27
        [created_at] =>
        [updated_at] =>
        [name] => Abc
    )
    [35] => Array (
        [id] => 35
        [created_at] =>
        [updated_at] =>
        [name] => Def
    )
)
```

**Question.** Is there a way to configure a query so that the first level keys of the returned array are equal to the IDs of the retrieved records?

Joomla's JDatabase has a [loadAssocList($key)](https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase/en#loadAssocList.28.24key.29) method that does exactly what I want to do in CodeIgniter.

Is it possible to configure the query in CodeIgniter to behave like the loadAssocList() method of Joomla's JDatabase? If this is not possible, what would be the best alternative?

Comment: The first "level" is the array index... So unless you'd actually want to loop through the array and change the keys each time, you should just leave that alone. Why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the Array with some additional PHP code.

```
// using your query ...
$query = $this->db->get('animals')->result_array();


// loop through each record of the result array and change its key positions   
foreach ($query as $key => $row) {
    $key_change = $row['id'];
    unset($query[$key]);
    $query[$key_change] = $row;
}


// view output (optional)
var_dump($query);
die();
```